# PHP MySQL query error

Tags: php, mysql

I have a problem with my PHP / SQL code. I have tried a lot and Googled but I cannot find which mistake I've made with the code.

I could not paste my code here, something went wrong, so I pasted it here

http://pastebin.com/P1Mur3Gv

```
$absentbijwerken = mysql_query("UPDATE hw_absentieregistratie SET '$currentweekandday' = '$aanwezigheid[$i]' WHERE userid = '$userid[$i]'")
or die(mysql_error());  
$absentredenbijwerken = mysql_query("UPDATE hw_absentiereden SET '$currentweekandday' = '$reden[$i]' WHERE userid = '$userid[$i]'")
or die(mysql_error());
```

Both queries get an error.

> MySQL error 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near '-Dinsdag = 'pr' WHERE userid = '1'' at line 1" You
>   have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to
>   your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '-Dinsdag =
>   'xd' WHERE userid = '1'' at line 1

EDIT:

The quotes were the issue, the new code looks like this:

```
for ( $i = 0; $i < count($userid); $i++){
$absentbijwerken = mysql_query("UPDATE hw_absentieregistratie SET `$currentweekandday` = '$aanwezigheid[$i]' WHERE userid = '$userid[$i]'") 
or die(mysql_error());  
$absentredenbijwerken = mysql_query("UPDATE hw_absentiereden SET `$currentweekandday` = '$reden[$i]' WHERE userid = '$userid[$i]'") 
or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: `$currentweekandday` is used as a column name. If it contains special characters (looks to have a `-` at least)`, you must enclose it in backquotes.  `SET \`$currentweekeandday\` = ...`

Comment: Don't build SQL like that. Even absent errors like the one you're seeing, it's a sure recipe for SQL injection.

Comment: Use caution when sending a variable as a column name. Check it against a list of possible acceptable values.

Comment: Please don't use the mysql_ family of functions. Use PDO or mysqli instead.

Comment: You have a column for each day?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enclose the column names in your queries with backticks:

```
$absentbijwerken = mysql_query("UPDATE hw_absentieregistratie SET `$currentweekandday` = '$aanwezigheid[$i]' WHERE `userid` = '$userid[$i]'")
or die(mysql_error());  
$absentredenbijwerken = mysql_query("UPDATE hw_absentiereden SET `$currentweekandday` = '$reden[$i]' WHERE `userid` = '$userid[$i]'")
or die(mysql_error());
```

It seems that the value passed in for `$currentweekandday` contains a `-`, which MySQL interprets as an operator, which doesn't fit in at that place.

<sup>`mysql_X` methods are deprecated. Switch to [PDO](http://php.net/PDO) or [mysqli](http://php.net/mysqli)!</sup>

Comment: Error has changed

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''w48-Dinsdag' = 'pr' WHERE userid = '1'' at line 1

Comment: @user1857116 You used the wrong quotes.  Backticks, not single quotes. Can you see the difference in the post above?

Comment: @user1857116 Could you provide the whole query, that is passed to MySQL? Just use an echo to show them.

Comment: Thanks, quotes were wrong, Michael Berkowski was right. Thanks again =D!